# Understanding HOCs with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions

I have a users component that just displays a list of users. I have tried to wrap it in a HOC loading component so that it only displays once the users are loaded, otherwise shows a loading spinner (well just text for now)

this is my HOC:

```
const Loading = (propName) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return this.props[propName].length === 0 ? <div> Loading... </div> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}

export default Loading;
```

at the bottom of my users component I have this:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Loading('users')(Users));
```

currently, the word `Loading...` is just staying on screen. and `propName` is coming through as `undefined`

I think for some reason the users component is never getting populated. what have i done wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this this.props[propName]?

Comment: Are any props coming through?

Comment: @Think-Twice I want to render the component based on the props

Comment: @jmargolisvt nope

Comment: @TheDecimator If your component doesn't receive any props, this probably means your `mapStateToProps` isn't defined correctly. Try `const mapStateToProps = () => ({ users: ['Ursuala User'] });` and see if `Users` is getting rendered for the mock data. Posting your `mapStateToProps` would also be helpful.

Comment: @FK82, but `Loading` component does not get its argument via `props` here. `Users` component gets some `users` prop maybe but how will `Loading` component get this? Here, OP is directly passing this as an argument. This is why there aren't any `props` in Loading component.

Comment: @devserkan sorry can you explain why it has no props. I thought they get passed down to the wrapper Loading component?

Comment: I FIXED IT!!. haha. soz. excited. it's because in that component I was fetching the users in `componentDidMount`.  so I pulled that out into it's own component and then just had a component to render the users and wrapping that in a loading comp, shows the spinner as the fetch is made and then once it has, they are there. woo. thanks for the help!

Comment: I was going to ask right now how do you get your users and how do you render this component. Since I don't get the structure from your question :) Glad that you solved your problem. You can provide a detailed answer about the solution and accept it.

Comment: i shall do that. why does that not work though?

Comment: As I looked at your code again, I see that I didn't quite understand it right! I also even misread some of your code :) In the first try you probably couldn't render your component properly, this is why you did not get any props.

Comment: I've updated my answer as much as I understand the situation :)

Comment: cheers, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update after comments**

My answer below is a misleading one since I hadn't understood your intention properly at that time. Also, my explanation about not getting `props` is somehow wrong. It is true if we don't render the components but here you are doing it. So, the problem was not that.

The problem here is your `Loading` component isn't rendered again after fetching users. Actually, you never fetch the users :) Here are the steps of your app (probably).

- You are exporting a HOC function, not the Wrapped one here. It comes from your `Users` file but it does not export the real `Users` component. This is important.
- Your parent renders the first time and it renders the exported HOC component.
- Your child component renders and fall into `Loading` one not the `Users` one.
- In `Loading` your `users` prop is empty, so you see **Loading...**.
- Your `Users` component never renders again. So, fetching the users there don't update the state.

Your solution is extracting the fetch out of `Users` and feed this component. Probably in a parent one. So:

- Parent fetches the users then renders itself and all its children.
- Your `Loading` HOC component renders a second time.

---

I don't know how do you plan to use this HOC but if I understood right (since I'm not so experienced with HOC) in your case the problem is you are not passing any `prop` to the `Loading` function. This is because you are not using it as a regular component here. It is a function and `propName` here is just an argument.

When we render a stateless function like this:

```
<Loading propName="foo" />
```

then there will be a `props` argument for our function. If we don't render it like that there will be no `props` argument and no `props.propName`. If this is wrong please somebody fix this and explain the right logic. So, you want to do something like this probably:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><FooWithLoading /></div>
    );
  }
}

const Loading = (users) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        users.length === 0 ? <div> Loading... </div> :
        <WrappedComponent
          users={users}
        />
      );
    }
  }
};

const Foo = props => {
return (
  <div>
    Users: {props.users}
  </div>
);
}

const FooWithLoading = Loading("foobar")(Foo);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

So in your case:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Loading('users')(Users));
```

should work?

Or you need to render your component properly in a suitable place of your app.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in the way the HOC is defined. You just uncurried his curried version. Both HOCs should be equivalent though.

Comment: @FK82, yes you are right. The main problem is not currying here. I've reverted it the original one.

Comment: @devserkan I would like to use currying and HOCs though. to improve my knowledge of them . I know how to render a component using a Loading component the conventional react way